# pandas Plot area by specifiying index column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My data looks like:

```
                       Club  Count
0            AC Milan            2
1                Ajax            1
2        FC Barcelona            4
3       Bayern Munich            2
4             Chelsea            1
5            Dortmund            1
6            FC Porto            1
7          Inter      Milan      1
8             Juventus           1
9           Liverpool            2
10              Man U            2
11        Real Madrid            7
```

I'm trying to plot an Area plot using Club as the X Axis, when plotting all data, it looks correct but the X axis displayed is the index and not the Clubs.
When specifying the index as Club(index=x), it shows correct, but the scale of the y axis is set from 0 to 0.05, assuming that's why nothing is displayed since the count is from 1 to 7 any suggestions ?

Code used:

```
data.columns = ['Club', 'Count']
x=data.Club
y=data.Count
print(data)
ax.margins(0, 10)
data.plot.area()
df = pd.DataFrame(y,index=x)
df.plot.area()
```

results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
df = pd.Series(y,index=x)
df.plot.area()
```

Comment: thanks it worked, i'll mark it as an answer, Doesn't it work with DataFrames as well ?
i was following one of the examples here where they used dataframes: https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-plot-area.php

Also, how can i ensure it uses all the X axis variables in the column?

Comment: @AdamSmithi think you use the chain operation , then it should pass the series ~